# Spring data throws an exception:" No property [property_name] found for type [Object]!"

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I would like a Spring Data interface to return a non-entity object.

I have googled and found a solution that I should use named queries with the result set mapping to a non-entity class.

However, I do resieve the described above exception. What causes this exception?

Here is my implementation of the sql result set mapping and named native query:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "revenue",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass = Revenue.class,
                        columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name = "date"),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "revenue")
                        }
                )
        }
)
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "calculateRevenueForGasStationName",
        query = "select fueling.date, fueling.price*fueling.volume as revenue from gas_station " +
                "left join fueling " +
                "on gas_station.id = fueling.gas_station " +
                "where fueling.date between ?1 and ?2 and gas_station.name=?3 " +
                "group by fueling.date",
        resultSetMapping = "revenue")
```

Here is the spring data interface method that should be linked to a `name = "calculateRevenueForGasStationName"`

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true)
List<Revenue> calculateRevenueForGasStationName(Date from, Date to, String name);
```

Comment: could you give us the full stacktrace ?

Comment: @AliDehghani it didn't help.

Comment: Did you try `name = "Revenue.calculateRevenueForGasStationName"`

Answer (score 0):

It seems problem with your class properties. Can you please revisit your Revenue.class property details.

Please make sure 
1) "date" property has declared as java.util.Date 
2) revenue has declared as Double 
3) Sample code is

```
`@SqlResultSetMapping( 
name = "revenue", 
classes = { @ConstructorResult( 
targetClass = Revenue.class, 
columns = { 
@ColumnResult(name = "date", type = java.util.Date.class), 
@ColumnResult(name = "revenue",type = Double.class) 
} ) } )`
```